# BIML: FilySystemTask is missing UseDirectoryIfExists attribute for operation Create Directory

Tags: biml

I'm trying to create a directory if it does not exists, using BIML. The SSIS File System Task has an operation `Create Directory` which has an `UseDirectoryIfExists` attribute, that can be set to true.

I cannot find that attribute for the `<FileSystem>` in BIML.

How can I set that property to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent used FileSystem in BIML yet, however i can give it a shot. Though i havent tested it.

You can also read more about the FileSystemTask properties [here](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstFileSystemTaskNode). As i can see it doesnt directly have an `UseDirectoryIfExists` property. However you can try what i have written below this.

This here is how a manuel SSIS-package XML looks like when you create a FileSystemTask with `UseDirectoryIFExists = true`

```
 <DTS:ObjectData> <FileSystemData TaskOperationType="CreateDirectory" TaskOverwriteDestFile="True" /> </DTS:ObjectData>
```

If `UseDirectoryIfExists = false`

Then it looks like this

```
<DTS:ObjectData> <FileSystemData TaskOperationType="CreateDirectory" /> </DTS:ObjectData>
```

So i think your BIML should look like this:

```
<Tasks> <FileSystem Operation="CreateDirectory" OverwriteDestination="true"> </FileSystem> </Tasks>
```